# Is it possible to execute a helper method before binding functionality executes?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I want to check a business rule before I bind the data the user enters into a textbox? Before I bind the data to the model, I need to ensure it meets a certain criteria. This would be very easy to do if I could execute a method before the binding occurs. Is there a way for me to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement [`ValidationRule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validationrule.aspx):

```
public class CustomValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    private static bool IsValid(string value)
    {
        // implement you business rule checking logic here
        // if valid
        //     return true;
        // else
        //     return fase;
    }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        var val = (string)value;
        if(IsValid(val))
        {
            return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Value is not valid");
        }
    }
}
```

And use it in your binding:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="ViewModelProperty" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <validation:CustomValidationRule />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Where `validation` is a XML namespace alias for namespace where `CustomValidationRule` is defined (add `xmlns:validation="clr-namespace:NAMESPACE_NAME_HERE"` to your XAML).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Binding Converter](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFgQFjAA&url=http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-binding-converters&ei=0Zf6T-6_BeX54QSj-4DtBg&usg=AFQjCNE61ivdRfajHJBqLRYr8vEp45oNqw&sig2=hAU_iV0kJAwVK_vgFBdRlA). The code you will write will be executed **before** binded value will be pushed on the UI. That is actually the *meaning* of converter: to give you ability to inject a code in the middle of bindind mechanism (*before* or *after* binding with UI executed)

Answer (score 1):

You can let your ViewModel which is bound to the view implements IDataErrorInfo.
This interface has a property and an indexer:

```
public string this[string columnName]
{
    //The validation logic goes here
    if( columnName == "Property1")
    {
        //put validation here and return error message if exists
        if(this.Property1 == "")
        {
             return "The field Property1 is required";
        }
    }
    //and so on
}

public string Error
{
    return "This object is not valid";
}
```

In the binding of the view add the following to the binding markup:

```
<TextBox Text={Binding Property1, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True} />
```

And don't forget to notify of property changed in your properties.

Hope this was helpful.